# Update shader graph based on an image value

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have a GLSL shader which has an if statement. That if statement checks if a texture is defined (using a bool uniform) and depending on that, it samples the texture or uses a default value

Pseudocode:

```
uniform bool hasTexture;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 defaultColor;

...
vec4 color = hasTexture ? texture(tex, uv) : defaultColor;
...
```

I am trying to replicate that on blender. For that purpose, I have ShaderNodeCustomGroup with an ImageTexture node and a RGB node. If the ImageTexture.image is None, the RGB output will be connected to the shader output, otherwise the ImageTexture color output will be connected. I am checking and updating the connections in the `draw_buttons` function of the ShaderNodeCustomGroup. I would like to know if there is some way to trigger an event and update the graph when the ImageTexture.image is updated, instead of doing this trick on the draw_buttons function.

I attach minimal working example.

[image]